Script could not be translated from: reference = "VNINDEX"
study("Relative Strength VN")

reference = "VNINDEX"
vnindex = security(reference, period, close)
rs = close/vnindex
sig = ema(rs, 20)

plot(rs, color=green, linewidth=3)
plot(sig, color=black, linewidth=1)

I put the code into Tradingview's Pine but got an error like this. What do I have to do to make this code work?

your code has no errors
